# p5.Vector not respecting angleMode

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I've noticed that when rotating vectors, the rotation is done in radians even after I have called `angleMode` with `DEGREES`. This behaviour only appears with vectors declared using the `new p5.Vector` syntax, while using `createVector` avoids it.

Minimal reproducible example: (paste into p5 web editor or OpenProcessing)

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 400)
    translate(100, 100) // To see the effect more clearly
    angleMode(DEGREES)
    let v = new p5.Vector(1, 0)
    line(0, 0, v.x * 50, v.y * 50)
    v.rotate(HALF_PI)
    line(0, 0, v.x * 50, v.y * 50)
}
```

Notice that the rotation is still done in radians. If you replace `new p5.Vector` with `createVector` then the problem disappears. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mathematically functions like [`sin()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/sin) are effected, there is no good reason why [`p5.Vector.rotate`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/rotate) should not be effected.
However it is not intended to construct a vector like you did. You should use [`createVector()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createVector) to create a vector. This function not only creates the object, but sets all internal attributes so that the objects behave as intended.

This behavior is not explained directly for [`rotate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/rotate), however it is documented for [`heading()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector/heading):

> Calculate the angle of rotation for this vector(only 2D vectors). **`p5.Vectors` created using `createVector()` will take the current `angleMode` into consideration**, and give the angle in radians or degree accordingly.

Comment: I've looked in the source code, and apparently `createVector` is doing a few things under the hood like passing the global `p5` object as a parameter into `new p5.Vector` which is what makes the global settings such as `angleMode` apply. This means that using `createVector` works as normal (it does in my case) and `new p5.Vector` doesn't. Check https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/main/src/math/p5.Vector.js at line 53.

Comment: @EnderShadow8 It is a documented behavior. I've changed the answer.